# How to immediately Identify an independent alert in Webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I know there are two types of alerts in webdriver, a dependent alert which is treated as part of the originating window and an independent alert treated as a different item from the originating window and requires below command to operate:

```
driver.switchTo().alert()
```

The question is: Is there any way to immediately identify if an alert is dependent or independent once it pops up without first having to execute code?

Answer (score 0):

As per question, an independent alert is a **browser popup**, which is operated with below command:

> driver.switchTo().alert();

Independent alert is not directly identified by WebDriver and driver needs to be switched to it.

The dependent alert is part of web application and WebDriver is able to locate elements present on it without switching.

Comment: jitendra.khedar, I am aware of this. What I really like to know is that when an alert is displayed, is there a way to immediately identify if the alert is dependent or dependent without code execution?